# Связь генерируемого элемента Buttom с конкретным элементом массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, table

Итак, суть проблемы: есть генерируемая таблица, которая тянет данные из массива. Есть точно такая же генерируемая "кнопка", которая добавляется в конце каждого ряда с данными таблицы (таб.1). [image: Таб.1]

Есть вторая таблица, которая генерируется похожим образом (таб.2):[image: Таб.2]

При нажатии на кнопку "Change card" №x (напр. 1 строка 1 таб) я перехожу в таб.2. Далее мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на "Accept" №y (напр.2 строка 2 таб) происходила замена данных элемента №x в массиве 1 (из него формируется таблица 1) на данные элемента №y массива 2 (который формирует таб 2).

Как я понимаю, мне нужно сначала привязать каждую сгенерированную кнопку "Chage card" к конкретному элементу массива таб.1 (таким образом мы будем запоминать, какой элемент нужно заменить). Далее точно так же нужно "привязать" кнопку "Accept" к элементам своего массива. После чего уже можно будет спокойно произвести замену элемента x из массива 1 на элемент y из массива 2.

Как мне привязать случайно гененрируемые кнопки к конкретному элементу массива, из которых формируются таблицы?

Comment: Имея элемент нажатой кнопки в скрипте вы всегда через его родителей можете узнать в какой строке она находится и запомнить в переменной какую то ключевую информацию об этой строке. После чего использовать эту сохраненную информацию при действиях в таблице2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
gen_btn.onclick = () => {
  gen_table.innerHTML = gen_row() + gen_row() + gen_row();
}

let array = [];
let num = 0;

function gen_row(){
  let row = `<tr data-num="${num++}">
               <td>${Math.random()}</td>
               <td>
                 <button onclick="click_handler(event)">нажми</button>
               </td>
             </tr>`;
  array.push(row);
  return row;
}

function click_handler(event){

  // Сам элемент, на который нажали
  let element = event.target;
  
  // Элемент строки
  let tr_element = element.closest('tr');
  
  // Номер строки в массиве
  let num = +tr_element.getAttribute('data-num');
  
  console.log( 'Номер: '+num );
  console.log( 'Элемент: '+array[num] );
}
```

```html
<button id=gen_btn>генерировать</button>
<table id=gen_table>
</table>
```

Как делается проброс замыканием?

Например, у вас уже есть кнопка или вы ее только что создали, пусть ссылка на неё будет в переменной `button`:

```
button.addEventListener('click', processThisAction(array[index]), false);

function processThisAction(arrayElement){
  // Этот код будет запущен во время создания кнопки
  // Здесь функция возвращает функцию
  return event => {
     // Этот код будет запущен по клику на кнопку
     // В event.target ссылка на кнопку
     console.log('target =', event.target);
     // Также есть доступ к элементу массива
     console.log('arrayElement=',arrayElement);
  };
}
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, кажется, я не совсем корректно изложил свою проблему. Мне не нужно, чтобы нажатие кнопки запоминало конкретное значение таблицы. Мне нужно, чтобы нажатие кнопки запоминало номер элемента массива, из которого сформирована строка таблицы и напротив которой находится активируемая кнопка.

Comment: @drakoblack исправил

Comment: Что-то здесь не так... Меня смущает, что Вы добавляете сгенерированные строки в НОВЫЙ массив. Таким образом, у вас кнопка получается частью массива, у меня же массивы уже готовые и кнопка генерируется отдельно (они не являются частью одного целого)... Так, даже если создать еще один массив сверху уже существующих и запихнуть туда кнопку, это не будет работать, так как кнопка будет запоминать порядковый номер элемента наружного массива, а не внутренних.

Comment: @drakoblack так дело не в массиве. Вы когда создаете кнопку, вы можете аргументами передать все индексы нужных массивов и по нажатию их можно будет прочитать.

Comment: @drakoblack а если делать без `innerHTML` то замыканием можно передать даже сам массив, не только индекс его элемента.

Comment: а можно это кодом изобразить? Я лишь около месяца активно занимаюсь изучением js и пытаюсь программировать на нем, поэтому большинство Ваших текстовых сообщений мне просто ничего не говорят (Я просто не понимаю, о чем идет речь).

Comment: А можете еще раз исправить код для запоминания значения в ячейке таблицы? Я, кажется, понял, как это можно использовать: Поскольку массив публикует данные в таблицу по порядку, я просто могу создать переменную, которая будет запоминать результат (значение ячейки - 1) - так я получу номер элемента массива, затем произвести замену данных не составит труда.

Comment: @drakoblack Да вы можете пробросить в функцию саму ячейку. Я кажется теперь понял вашу проблему. Вам нужно правильное замыкание, а не атрибуты ячейки.

Comment: наверное... Честно говоря, не совсем понимаю Вас. Я знаю, что такое "атрибут", но не понимаю, что значит "замыкание".

Comment: @drakoblack я добавил немного кода в текст ответа

Comment: Спасибо, поизучаю. Надеюсь, это прояснит тот лес вопросов, которые у меня возникают.

Answer (score 0):

Короче решил свою проблему вот так:

```
//Нужны две глобальные переменные, кторые будут передавать полученные результаты между функциями
 let index_X = 0;
 let index_Y = 0;

// Данная функция стоит таблицу "my_deck"
function BackMyDeck(index_X, index_Y) {
  var num = 0; // порядковый номер в таблице
  var numb = 0; // данная переменная генерирует число, которое будет определять строку в таблице, которую нужно заменить
  document.querySelector('.my_deck').innerHTML = '<table class="my_cards"></table>';
  var row1 = document.createElement('tr');
  row1.innerHTML = '<td>Number</td><td>Class</td><td>Attak</td><td>Attak type</td><td>Accuracy</td><td>Health</td><td>Defence</td><td>Speed</td><td>Dexterity</td><td>Change card</td>';
  document.querySelector('.my_cards').appendChild(row1);

DECK_PL.forEach(c => {
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  row.innerHTML = `<td>${num++}</td><td>${c.suits}</td><td>${c.attak}</td><td>${c.attaktipe}</td><td>${c.accuracy}</td><td>${c.health}</td><td>${c.defence}</td><td>${c.speed}</td><td>${c.dexterity}</td><td><button onclick='ChangeCards(${numb++})'>Change card</button></td>`;
  document.querySelector('.my_cards').appendChild(row);
  });
};

BackMyDeck(); // Генерация первой таблицы "my_deck"

// Генерация таблицы "Change Cards", в которой перечислены все доступные карты и их количество
function ChangeCards(index_X) {
  console.log('ChangeCards.numX:'+index_X );
  var num2 = 0;
  var numb2 = 0; // данная переменная генерирует число, которое определяет строку в таблице "my_cards", которая будет использована для замены строки "numb" в таблице "my_deck"
  document.querySelector('.my_deck').innerHTML = '<table class="my_cards"></table><p>Back to My Deck =></p><button onclick="BackMyDeck()"> Back My Deck </button>'; //Создание таблицы и копки для возврата на изначальную таблицу "my_deck" без изменений колоды
  var row1 = document.createElement('tr');
  row1.innerHTML = '<td>Number</td><td>Cards</td><td>Selection</td><td>Total cards</td>';
  document.querySelector('.my_cards').appendChild(row1);

ALLCARDS.forEach(c => {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML = `<td>${num2++}</td><td>${c.suits}</td><td><button onclick="Accept(${index_X}, ${numb2++})">Accept</button></td><td>max</td>`;
    document.querySelector('.my_cards').appendChild(row);
  });
}

// Данная функуия производит замену значений в таблице "my_deck" на выбранное значение таблицы "my_cards" после чего генерирует обновленную таблицу "my_deck"
function Accept(index_X, index_Y) {
    console.log('Accept.numX:'+index_X );
    console.log('Accept.numY:'+index_Y );
  DECK_PL[index_X] = ALLCARDS[index_Y];
  BackMyDeck();
};
```